# Skip an element when copying the whole node in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Is it possible to skip an element from a node? For example we have node as `Test` and it has child elements `x`, `y`,`z`. I want to copy the whole `Test` node but don't want `z` element in the final result. Can we use `not()` in `copy-of select`? I tried but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `<xsl:copy-of>` gives you no control over what happens inside what you are copying. That's what an identity template with selective omissions is for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Test" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Omit z from the results-->
  <xsl:template match="z" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML:

```
<n>
  <Test>
    <x>Hello</x>
    <y>Heeelo</y>
    <z>Hullo</z>
  </Test>
</n>
```

The result is:

```
<Test>
  <x>Hello</x>
  <y>Heeelo</y>

</Test>
```